# Adding property - value in a javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Today i'm facing a really strange behavior, check this out !

```
const person = [];
person.name = "Hello World"
console.log(person) // [name: "Hello World"]
```

That is crazy, I just pushed some key - value pair in a javascript array ?
Can someone explain to me what just happened ? :)

Have a good day

Comment: When I'm running that exact code on codesandbox.io my the output is just an empty array. What are you using to compile/run the code?

Comment: Just open the console(f12) and try it out :)